# Opening an erlang shell from bash

Tags: shell, compilation, erlang

Hello is there any way to open an erlang shell from bash ? I do not want everytime to insert manually the path of the files(s) that i am compiling.Can't i just open a shell in my target folder and open erlang which would take it as current dir ?

Every time i want to load a module i have to do it manually:
`c([path to module])` -> change the backslashes

**P.S** : I am using `vscode` and it would be really helpful to have the code visible while i open the integrated terminal and load the modules.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `rebar3` - https://www.rebar3.org/, or `Erlang.mk` - https://erlang.mk/, or you can create your own `Makefile` for compile your modules, moved to some folders and run shell from folders where you have `*.beam` files after compile. For example, do compile from `src` folder to eg. `_build` folder and run

```sh
$ mkdir -p _build && erlc -o _build/ src/*.erl
$ cd _build && erl
```